# Preventing Entity Framework from nulling out foreign keys when soft deleting

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I have inherited a web application with a database that doesn't delete rows (for auditing reasons) and instead has a "Deleted" flag that must be checked when selecting or joining the table. It's been brought over to Entity Framework 5, and in an attempt to automate this system, the DbContext has been modified with something like the following code:

```
public class DbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var deletedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x=>x.State == EntityState.Deleted).ToArray();
        foreach(var entityEntry in deletedEntities)
        {
            try
            {
                dynamic entity = entityEntry.Entity;
                entity.Deleted = true;

                entityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            catch(RuntimeBinderException)
            {
                //allow hard delete
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The actual code is more complicated because it also sets updated time, updated user, detects new objects and sets their created time/user, etc.

We've run into a problem, though, when we have objects that have foreign keys associated with them and the code loads those associated objects. The FKs that refer to the deleted object get nulled out.

The EF code is in Database First mode, because the database existed long before the company decided to switch to Entity Framework, and the database's FK constraints are all "ON DELETE NO ACTION", so we wouldn't expect the FK to be set to null if it was following the database's design.

We understand that Entity Framework doesn't want to orphan them, but the existing design calls for them to remain unchanged. We expect and require (for audit reasons) that the foreign keys continue pointing to the "deleted" row (Again, regular queries filter out deleted rows). One reason for this is so that if the customer calls us about "accidentally" deleting something, we can just flip the flag and everything will "just work". I cannot change this design.

For example, take this simplified scenario code:

```
//FooBarContext derives from the above DbContext and was generated from a database using Database First
using(var context = new FoobarContext())
{
    var foo = context.FOO.Find(fooId);
    var bar = foo.Bar;
    context.BAR.Remove(bar);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

So I "delete" the Bar object that belongs to the foo object, the Bar.Deleted is set to true and the Bar is updated instead of deleted. But the foo object, which has been loaded into the context, recognizes that the bar object was "deleted" and "foo.BarId" is set to `NULL` and this change propogates when SaveChanges is called. We would like "foo.BarId" to remain the same value.

Is there any way to tell Entity Framework to stop nulling out foreign keys in database first mode?

Comment: This is slightly more complicated approach we use succesfully for years. Should do the job you need, let me know if this suits you as an answer: http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2013/10/soft-delete-pattern-for-entity.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are tagging your entities as modified.

The question is, the objects you are tagging so, area they being loaded from the database and updated using the same context instance?

If not, when attaching them, are you attaching them with their foreign keys properly set (you could be mapping them from view models or business models without having transported the FKs values)?

Because, if not, EF will asumme you are nulling the FKs (0 or empty string in an FK is NULL db-wise).